# Rails multiple joins AR query and where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendation_sets, :through => :product_recommendation_sets
end

class ProductRecommendationSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :recommendation_set
end

class RecommendationSet < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :product_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_recommendation_sets

  has_many :recommendation_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :recommendation_recommendation_sets
end

class RecommendationRecommendationSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recommendation
  belongs_to :recommendation_set
end

class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :recommendation_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :recommendations, :through => :recommendation_recommendation_sets
end
```

Im trying to select all `recommendations` where product_id = `x`, by doing:

```
RecommendationSet.joins(:products, :recommendations).where(product_id:1)
```

However I get an unknown column error. How can I join select all recommendations by a given product_id.
Psudo code: 
Find `recommendation_sets` where `product_id = ?`. Find `recommendations` where `recommendation_set_id = ?`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were pretty close, **in your case** this should work:

```
RecommendationSet.joins(:products, :recommendations).where(products: { id: 1 })
```

---

Remember that **in the where clause you have to use the table's name** in the conditons hash, not the relation's name.

As an Example, consider these relations:

```
User belongs_to :group
Group has_many :users
```

Notice the syntax (plural / singular):

```
User.joins(:group).where(groups: { name: 'Admin' })
#               ^             ^
Group.joins(:users).where(users: { id: 15 })
#                ^            ^
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns all the `RecommendationSets`, how can I return all the `recommendations` also, so something like `RecommendationSet.joins(:products, :recommendations).where(products: { id: 1 }).recommendations`

Comment: Yes you can call .recommendations on each element of the returned list ;)